# Having issues displaying SCSS correctly

Tags: html, css, sass

Good Evening all, I am trying to re-create a login page for my project, I am going to have roughly 20 html page's and I am trying attach all of my html files to the one CSS file. In order to do that I know I have to assign the parameters of my css elements so that they are only assigned to a singular page. In this case, I am trying to assign these SCSS elements only to my login page. However, the right side of my page is not displaying as it should. I have searched everywhere, and I am not sure of what I am doing wrong. Can anyone more experienced give me an idea of how I could handle this differently to get the intended result? Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>blank title</title>
</head>
<body class = loginPage>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="header">
      <h2 class="animation a1">Welcome Back</h2>
      <h4 class="animation a2">Log in to your account using email and password</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <input type="email" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Email Address">
      <input type="password" class="form-field animation a4" placeholder="Password">
      <p class="animation a5"><a href="#">Forgot Password</a></p>
      <button class="animation a6">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500&display=swap');


.loginPage .body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
.loginpage .container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.loginpage .left {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  animation-name: left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550745165-9bc0b252726f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}



.loginPage .header > h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #4f46a5;
}

.loginPage .header > h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.loginPage .form {
  max-width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loginPage .form > p {
  text-align: right;
}

.loginPage .form > p > a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.loginPage .form-field {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.loginPage .form-field:focus {
  border-color: #0f7ef1;
}

.loginPage .form > button {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #de48b5 0%, #0097ff 100%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.loginPage .animation {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a1 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a2 {
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

.loginPage .a3 {
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

.loginPage .a4 {
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}

.loginPage .a5 {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.loginPage .a6 {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes .loginPage .move {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes .loginPage .left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    width: 440px;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqGZ9.jpg)

Comment: go to https://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php and enter your scss  and use the  Compile SCSS button and you will see what the issue issue.  It is the @keyframes  using the class selectors that seem to be an issue

Comment: here's the syntax for @keyframes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this was an issue with typing the code into StackOverflow or if your base code is like this but there are several issues with class names both in the HTML and CSS that are causing some errors.  For example, your loginPage class name for the body is not surrounded by quotations so that will cause errors with the class names in your CSS.  Also, there are several .loginPage identifiers in the CSS that are typed in as .loginpage, which again would cause errors as the CSS won't tie that with the class name in the HTML.  Furthermore, .loginPage .body in your CSS won't do anything as the body is an element tag, not a class name.  Since this is the main part of your code, I would just recommend changing that to .loginPage.  After the changes were made to those typos, your page started looking more like what you provided.

Next, I started off by changing the .loginPage CSS section to be `display: flex` so that I could make some flexbox style layout.  I changed the .loginPage .container section to be `display: inline-flex` with `height: 100vh` to cover the entire viewport and prevent the child elements from being block level and taking up the entire width of the page, which would push your picture down below the container.  I then set `height: 100vh` for the .right element to again take up the entire viewport, set `width: 80%` to bring both the .container and the .right elements on the same line, and combined your separate background css into one for simplification.

There are some other modifications I made for appearance, such as margin on the .loginPage .container and flex specifications on that one as well as the .right element.  Below is the final code.  When using this code in your project, I would recommend playing around with the margins and flex specification though just to make sure it works across various screen sizes.  I hope this answers your question!

```
<body class="loginPage">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="animation a1">Welcome Back</h2>
        <h4 class="animation a2">Log in to your account using email and password</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <input type="email" class="form-field animation a3" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="password" class="form-field animation a4" placeholder="Password">
        <p class="animation a5"><a href="#">Forgot Password</a></p>
        <button class="animation a6">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500&display=swap');

.loginPage {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}

.loginPage .container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.loginPage .left {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  animation-name: left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: 1s;
  background: center / cover no-repeat url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550745165-9bc0b252726f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80);
}

.loginPage .header > h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #4f46a5;
}

.loginPage .header > h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.loginPage .form {
  max-width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loginPage .form > p {
  text-align: right;
}

.loginPage .form > p > a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.loginPage .form-field {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.loginPage .form-field:focus {
  border-color: #0f7ef1;
}

.loginPage .form > button {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #de48b5 0%, #0097ff 100%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.loginPage .animation {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a1 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a2 {
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

.loginPage .a3 {
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

.loginPage .a4 {
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}

.loginPage .a5 {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.loginPage .a6 {
   animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes .loginPage .move {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes .loginPage .left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    width: 440px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! I learned so much from this post, thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me! it works perfectly and you explained everything thoroughly so I know in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Giving your @keyframes the proper animation name you used seemed to compile well
https://jsfiddle.net/oeat97m2/

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500&display=swap');


.loginPage .body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
.loginpage .container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.loginpage .left {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  animation-name: left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550745165-9bc0b252726f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}



.loginPage .header > h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #4f46a5;
}

.loginPage .header > h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.loginPage .form {
  max-width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loginPage .form > p {
  text-align: right;
}

.loginPage .form > p > a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.loginPage .form-field {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.loginPage .form-field:focus {
  border-color: #0f7ef1;
}

.loginPage .form > button {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #de48b5 0%, #0097ff 100%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.loginPage .animation {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a1 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.loginPage .a2 {
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

.loginPage .a3 {
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

.loginPage .a4 {
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}

.loginPage .a5 {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.loginPage .a6 {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-40px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

 @keyframes left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    width: 440px;
  }
}
```